# Is there a way to map Ctrl period and Ctrl comma in Vim?

Tags: vim

I can't seem to find a way to map `<control> period` and `<control> comma` in Vim. Is it possible?

Comment: FYI, you can map those with Meta (like `noremap <M-.> :echo "dot!"<CR>`) but not Ctrl  (Meta is usually Alt)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

According to [the FAQ](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.5) it looks like you're out of luck with `<C-.>` and `<C-,>`, since this key combination is not in the list of Ctrl-printable-key chords that Vim can detect (Vim can only map to printable ASCII chords).

Comment: Thanks for the info! Not what I wanted to hear, but at least I know it can't be done now, so I can stop trying to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 16):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>non-alphabetic</kbd> cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>letter</kbd> vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>letter</kbd> cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated [various proposals](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8).

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.

Answer (score 4):

It seems @Prince Goulash is correct, but I have found a solution that has worked for my needs. How I got around this limitation is by creating bindings in my actual terminal emulator, which allows bindings such as `<C-,>`, that outputs a random string (so I don't accidentally hit it, usually 3 nums followed by the char I want bound with ctrl) which is then bound to the command I wanted it to be bound to in vim. Not quite as portable, but it's worked like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

Don't be so pessimistic about making  a shortcut. There are outside options. Try the following code in AutoHotKey.  [All you need is download and install AHK and run the following code as a script.]

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Vim
^+!left:: send :s/{^}/`%/g{Enter}{$}o{enter} ; This is for commenting in tex files. you may change `% to be other symbles. 
^,:: send ^ww
+^,:: send ^wW
```

Hope this would help with your problem.

Comment: `._ .` `o_O` `T_T`