# Cant remap <C-/> or any alt + key in vim with ConEmu

Tags: vim, conemu

I running into issues remapping Ctrl+{Punctuation} as well as Alt+{AnyKey} in VIM while using conemu as my terminal. I'm also running Windows 10. To be honest, I'm not sure if this a Windows VIM issue or just a ConEmu VIM issue.

Let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 0):

So, after doing some extra research I found some answers.

Essentially, VIM will not recognize certain Ctrl+{Keys}. Here is some reasoning as to why: http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.5. More info here: [Is there a way to map Ctrl period and Ctrl comma in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033779/is-there-a-way-to-map-ctrl-period-and-ctrl-comma-in-vim)

Also, my Windows terminal appears to be sending the Esc+{Key} when I press Alt+{Key}. I found a workaround here: [Alt key shortcuts not working on gnome terminal with Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778961/alt-key-shortcuts-not-working-on-gnome-terminal-with-vim)